# Show website on its all height on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, web, height

My website's dimensions are 940 x 800. It looks nice when my iPad is in vertical position, but when I turn it to landscape mode I only see less than a half of my site. It looks like it's trying to fit my website's width while I only care on fitting its height. I tried using this meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">
```

So, I'm wondering if I actually can force my iPad and any other tablet or mobile device to show my website on its complete height on landscape mode. I don't really care that much if it looks tiny at first because I'd like people to zoom-in if they need to.

I hope I made myself clear, I apologize if I messed up width my english.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it adding to the viewport tag's width the height of my site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1740,height=800,initial-scale=0">
```